# laravel 5.5 package developing need to use composer require vendor_name/package_name

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php, package, packagist

I developed a Laravel 5.5 package with package auto discovery and pushed it at git hub

```
https://github.com/adamibrahim/authconfirm
```

when i run

```
$ composer require "adamibrahim/authconfirm" : "v0.1.1"
```

I got an error

```
could not find package adamibrahim/authconfirm at any version for your min ...
```

do i need to register my repository somewhere so i can use composer require command ?

here is my package composer.json

```
{
"name": "adamibrahim/authconfirm",
"type": "library",
"description": ":Laravel 5.5 Auth modifications to confirm the auth email",
"keywords": [
    "Laravel5.5",
    "Auth",
],
"homepage": "https://github.com/adamibrahim/authconfirm",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": ":Adam Ibrahim",
        "email": ":adamibrahim1701@gmail.com",
        "homepage": ":author_website",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
],
"require": {
    "illuminate/support": "~5.1",
    "php" : "~5.6|~7.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit" : ">=5.4.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Adamibrahim\\Authconfirm\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Adamibrahim\\Authconfirm\\": "tests"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
    }
},
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not enough just to create Github repository to use it via composer. You should create account at https://packagist.org/ and add your package in there to make it available via `composer require`.

In addition you should setup Packagist integration on Github at:

```
https://github.com/adamibrahim/authconfirm/settings/installations
```

to make sure after changes in Github Packagist will see those changes.

Comment: Thanks for response will check that , and give a try

Comment: Of course, you do this when you are ready to publish to packagist. Until then, you can install using composer directly from Github, or some other repositories. Details on how to do this can be found here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs